# mySQL multiple join select results as columns in single row

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I've been wrestling with this query all of yesterday. I've simplified the joins down to just the bare minimum, as it was producing really odd results.

It's now doing what i 'expect' it to do, but not what i want it to do... ideally i want a single row which returns day_1, day_2 and day_3 if they're rows within event_attendee_days.

```
SELECT event_attendees.id, event_attendees.name, event_account.name AS company,

case event_attendee_days.days_id
when '1' then "25th"
ELSE "-"
end AS day_1,

case event_attendee_days.days_id
when '2' then "26th"
ELSE "-"
end AS day_2,

case event_attendee_days.days_id
when '3' then "27th"
ELSE "-"
end AS day_3,

event_account.email, event_account.telephone, acct_type, acct, address1, address2,     address3, address4, postcode, business_type, business_desc, signup

FROM event_attendees
JOIN event_account ON event_attendees.acct_id = event_account.id
LEFT JOIN event_attendee_days ON event_attendees.id = event_attendee_days.user_id

WHERE event_attendees.id = "1019"

ORDER BY event_attendees.acct_id
```

Currently produces (i've skipped unrequired files in this example.)

```
id   |   day_1  |   day_2  |   day_3
1019 |   25th   |   -      |   -
1019 |   -      |   26th   |   -
1019 |   -      |   -      |   27th
```

However i want

```
id   |   day_1  |   day_2  |   day_3  | ...
1019 |   25th   |   26th   |   27th   | ...
1020 |   -      |   -      |   27th   | ...
```

etc. I've had a few different goes at it, and this is the closest i've came so far. Just need to condense the results down to a single row without losing information :-)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
SELECT
    id,
    MAX(day_1) AS day_1,
    MAX(day_2) AS day_2,
    MAX(day_3) AS day_3
FROM
    event
GROUP BY
    id;
```

[I made an SQL Fiddle here, feel free to test it here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/69767/9)

You'll still need to manually input all the days you want, though.

Hope it helps

PS: on my fiddle, that table is named "event", by the way